# Get view (chart) item from controller

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs-mvc

I have a chart with a text item :

```
 Ext.define('MyProject.view.DrawChart', {
   extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
   alias: 'widget.drawchart',
   requires: ['Ext.chart.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.layout.container.Fit'],
   default chart settings here

    ...

   items: [{
      type  : 'text',
      text  : 'Simple Title',
      font  : '14px Arial',
      id : 'chartTitle',
      width : 100,
      height: 30,
      x : 50, //the sprite x position
      y : 10  //the sprite y position
   }]
})
```

I need to customize the `text` property of that item from the controller.
How can I access or reference that item? I have tried the usual reference :

`this.getDrawChart().down('text #chartTitle').title`

Nothing works! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly did you want to customize on the `text` property?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Ext.getCmp('chartTitle');
```

Where `chartTitle` is the `id` of the element.

Once you got an element you can use `.getCls()`, `.setCls()` and `.addCls()` or `.removeCls()` to get, set or add `CSS` classes.

Like:

```
var title = Ext.getCmp('chartTitle');
title.addCls('newStyle');
```